# Apple watchOS 3 program ended with exit code 0: did tapped on remote notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, watchos-3

I am using "User Notifications framework" to show remote notifications, working on iOS version 10.2 and watch version 3.1.Everything is working perfect for iPhone app but in watch while user receives notification. Did tapped on notification default action it showing log in console

> Program ended with exit code 0 
>   and application relaunching.

after that its calling delegate

```
 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

but I want to call this delegate without app relaunch